# Redux-Saga: Is there a guaranteed order of saga execution?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

If i have two sagas waiting for a `yield take()` on the same action, is there a guarantee which saga will pick up the action first and execute its remaining logic or is random? I need to ensure the first saga executes its logic before the second saga does.

```
function* rootSaga() {
    yield [ 
        saga1(),
        saga2()
    ]
}

function* saga1() {
    while (true) {
        //Random logic
        yield take("MY_ACTION")
        //Finish executing logic
    }
}

function* saga2() {
    while (true) {
        //Random logic
        yield take("MY_ACTION")
        //Finish executing logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You cannot rely here on the order of execution. When your action is dispatched, all sagas that have yielded a `take` effect matching the action will be resumed at once. If an order of execution was "guaranteed", it would be an implementation detail you shouldn't rely on.

If you need your `saga2` to be resumed after `saga1` has executed the logic subsequent to `"MY_ACTION"`, what your `saga2` should really be waiting for is a different action indicating that `saga1` has finished its job, rather than the first one.

```
function* rootSaga() {
  yield [ 
    saga1(),
    saga2()
  ]
}

function* saga1() {
  while (true) {
    //Random logic
    yield take("MY_ACTION")
    //Finish executing logic
    yield put({type: "MY_ACTION_DONE"})
  }
}

function* saga2() {
  while (true) {
    //Random logic
    yield take("MY_ACTION_DONE")
    //Finish executing logic
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Rather than having both run independently, you can call or fork the dependent generator from the initial one after the necessary logic has been performed.

Note there is a subtle but important difference between `call` and `fork`. `call(saga2)` is blocking so would pause your while loop and not react to any more `"MY_ACTION"` actions until saga2 has completed too, whereas `fork(saga2)` is non-blocking, acting like a background task so would continue to execute in parallel to your loop resuming, so you could continue to respond to further `"MY_ACTION"`.

Another thing to note is that `fork` is still attached to the parent saga, so will be cancelled along with it, errors will bubble to parent from it etc. I imagine this is desirable but if you need a completely detached version that will continue to run no matter what happens to parent saga, use `spawn` instead

```
function* rootSaga() {
    yield all([ 
        fork(saga1)
    ])
}

function* saga1() {
    while (true) {
        //Random logic
        const action = yield take("MY_ACTION")
        //Finish executing logic

        // BLOCKING `call` saga2, passing original action as param if needed
        yield call(saga2, action)

        // OR NON-BLOCKING `fork` saga2
        yield fork(saga2, action)

        // OR NON-BLOCKING DETACHED `spawn` saga2
        yield spawn(saga2, action)
    }
}

function* saga2(action) {
    // Do whatever dependant logic
    // safe in the knowledge that saga1 has done its job already
}
```